# DNSMASQ Specify Port Number in dhcp-option=6

Tags: dnsmasq, dhcp-option

I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I want to redirect DNS requests coming from some ip[-range] to another instance of `dnsmasq` on `port 1995`. To do so I added these lines in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` file :

```
dhcp-range=set:red,10.10.10.11,10.10.10.222,255.255.255.0,12h
dhcp-option=tag:red,6,10.10.10.10:1995
```

But when I restart `dnsmasq` it fails telling that `Bad IP address on line ...`

I also tried

```
dhcp-option=tag:red,6,10.10.10.10#1995
```

This also fails as `Bad IP Address`

Now, tell me how to specify the port number of other DNS Servers in `dhcp-option` ?

Answer (score 3):

When it comes down to it, the issue here is not so much `dnsmasq` but rather the DHCP protocol itself.

Option 6 has no field for holding any port, only a sequence of 4 octet/byte (32 bit) IPv4 addresses.

From [RFC2132: DHCP Options and BOOTP Vendor Extensions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132#section-3.8):

```
3.8. Domain Name Server Option

   The domain name server option specifies a list of Domain Name System
   (STD 13, RFC 1035 [8]) name servers available to the client.  Servers
   SHOULD be listed in order of preference.

   The code for the domain name server option is 6.  The minimum length
   for this option is 4 octets, and the length MUST always be a multiple
   of 4.

    Code   Len         Address 1               Address 2
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--
   |  6  |  n  |  a1 |  a2 |  a3 |  a4 |  a1 |  a2 |  ...
   +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+--
```

Unless you're changing the overall approach, you'll want to put your different nameservers on different addresses rather than on different ports.